# Heroku deploy "Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified", worked yesterday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was able to deploy to heroku yesterday just fine.  We're on the cedar stack with a rails 3.2 application.  When I deploy it gives me this:

```
$ git push -f heroku-ab-staging  tmp-heroku-deploy-gochez_heroku_test-2012-05-08-10-43-39:master
Counting objects: 222, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (162/162), done.
Writing objects: 100% (191/191), 112.28 KiB, done.
Total 191 (delta 45), reused 13 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
 !
 !     Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified: fatal:-Not-a-git-repository:-'.'-fatal:-Not-a-git-repository:-'.'-fatal:-Not-a-git-repository:-'.'-No-ruby-version-specified
 !     Valid versions: ruby-1.9.3-p0, ruby-1.9.3-p125, rbx-1.2.4, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120115-1.9, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120115-1.8, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120123-1.9, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120123-1.8, ruby-1.9.2-p290, jruby-1.6.5.1, jruby-1.6.7, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9.2
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] tmp-heroku-deploy-gochez_heroku_test-2012-05-08-10-43-39 -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:myapp.git'
```

(Note that I changed my real app's name to `myapp` for privacy concerns)

Any idea what might be causing this?  It was working just fine yesterday.  What debugging can I perform to figure out what the issue is?

Comment: What version of `ruby` are you using?  It says:
`Valid versions: ruby-1.9.3-p0, ruby-1.9.3-p125, ...`

Comment: `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]`  that's what i am in locally when I perform the deploy... (which is in the list)... Where is it getting this RUBY_VERSION from though?  Because it doesn't look at my *local* ruby version to define what to use on the heroku server, right?

Comment: RUBY_VERSION is a heroku config variable, inspect via `heroku config` to see what/if it's been set.

Comment: nothing was being set, and specifically setting it with `heroku config:add RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.2-p290` didn't seem to have an effect either.  I had a support ticket open but the issue resolved itself before they came up with a solution for me.  Dunno what the problem was.

Comment: I had this recently and it was caused by a syntax error in my Gemfile. Check "bundle install" runs without errors locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We changed the undocumented API you were using and released official version ruby support: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku/ You'll now need to use Bundler 1.2.0 +. Let me know if you have questions.